# If $x \in NulA$ and $\vec b \in col(A^T)$ then $\vec x$ and $ \vec b $ are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure how to prove this one. There's a hint given: Recall $[\vec x \cdot \vec y] =  (\vec x)^T \vec y.$

Comment: Here's another hint: $\vec{b}=A^T\vec{y}$ for some $\vec{y}$

Answer (score 1):

You can write $A$ as $A = \displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} \vec a_1 \\ \vdots \\\vec a_n \end{bmatrix}$ so that the matrix product $A \vec x$ is given by $$A \vec x = \begin{bmatrix}\vec a_1 \cdot \vec x \\ \vdots \\ \vec a_n \cdot \vec x \end{bmatrix}$$Observe $x \in \mathrm{null}(A)$if and only if $\vec a_i \cdot \vec x = 0$ for all $i$, and in particular if and only if $\vec x$ is orthogonal to the row space of $A$. Now work with the transpose.

Comment: thank you very much I'll try and work it out...